# Searching for specific string pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to be able to search for a specific string that has this format:

```
"q4-2015"
"q2-2013"
"q3-2011"
```

from a long list of file names and break them down into two variables:
quarter and year.

so example a long list of names can include:

```
"aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file"
"aaaaaa-fffff-3333-q2-2012-file"
```

and the code should loop through the file names and then throw out the specific variables, in the first case,

```
year = 2015, quarter = q4
```

and in second case:

```
year = 2012, quarter = q2
```

etc

Comment: So what have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
quarters <- sapply(input, function(x) {
    sub(".*\\b(q\\d+)-\\d{4}\\b.*", "\\1", x)
})

years <- sapply(input, function(x) {
    sub(".*\\bq\\d+-(\\d{4})\\b.*", "\\1", x)
})

df <- data.frame(quarters, years)
df

        quarters years
q4-2015       q4  2015
q2-2013       q2  2013
q3-2011       q3  2011
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try with this pattern

```
captured_words <- sub(".*\\b(q\\d)-(\\d+)\\b.*", "\\1-\\2", x)
captured_words
#[1] "q4-2015" "q2-2012"
```

Here, we capture two terms:

1) `q` followed by a single digit number and 2) the numbers following that.

We can separate them and read them in a dataframe using `read.table`

```
read.table(text = paste0(captured_words, collapse = "\n"), sep = "-")

#  V1   V2
#1 q4 2015
#2 q2 2012
```

**data**

```
x <- c("aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file","aaaaaa-fffff-3333-q2-2012-file")
```

Comment: Good answer +1, but you may wish to add boundaries on either side of your pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. However, I am not clear about boundaries. What does it do/prevent?

Comment: Your current pattern would match e.g. `xxxx-aq4-1994blah-yyyy`.  But, you wouldn't want that to happen.  Boundaries prevent this.

Comment: @user7729135 In that case remove the "-" in both the answers and it should work. But make sure the pattern is consistent throughout. It will not work if you have some values as `f4q07"` and some as `f4q-07"`.

Comment: What output do you get for `sub(".*\\b(q\\d)(\\d+)\\b.*", "\\1-\\2", x)` ? where `x` is your long list of names.

Comment: @RonakShah i got back x

Answer (score 0):

**1) strcapture** Using the test input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end can invoke `strcapture` from base R:

```
pat <- "(q\\d)-(\\d{4})"
strcapture(pat, x, list(quarter = "", year = 0))
```

giving:

```
  quarter year
1      q4 2015
2      q2 2012
```

An alternative might be to have a numeric quarter column.  In that case we would use `pat <- "(\\d)-(\\d{4})"` and `list(quarter = 0, year = 0)`.

**2) read.pattern** `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package could be used with the same pattern.

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = x, pattern = pat, col.names = c("quarter", "year"),
  as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  quarter year
1      q4 2015
2      q2 2012
```

**2a)** Another approach is to use gsubfn's `strapply` to produce a `yearqtr` class object and then we could readily extract the quarter and year or we could just leave it as a yearmon object:

```
library(gsubfn)
library(zoo)

ym  <- do.call("c", 
  strapply(x, pat, q + y ~ as.yearqtr(paste(y, q, sep = "-"))))

ym
## [1] "2015 Q4" "2012 Q2"

data.frame(quarter = paste0("q", cycle(ym), year = as.integer(ym),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
##   quarter year
## 1      q4 2015
## 2      q2 2012
```

### Note

```
# test input
x <- c("aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file",
  "aaaaaa-fffff-3333-q2-2012-file")
```